# linked table or sub queries?

Tags: sql

I was looking up different ways to write a query, and I'm just wondering which way do you all think is better way to go with the following options:

```
SELECT a.salary 
  FROM emp a
  JOIN emp b ON a.salary < b.salary
 WHERE b.id = 200
```

or

```
SELECT salary 
  FROM emp
 WHERE salary < (SELECT salary 
                   FROM emp 
                  WHERE id = 200)
```

I did some execution times with about 300 records in the table, and they come out about the same, so this is really just more about preference and accepted standards.  I personally like the 2nd way better (just easier to read to me).  I have a feeling the 1st is standard though.  What do you all think?

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32705705/join-vs-subquery.aspx

Comment: You need to check execution plan and choose the query that uses the best one. Depends on RDMS, these queries may or may not generate the same plan. You can also rewrite the query to use `EXIST` or `NOT EXIST` and check their execution plan as well.

Comment: Wow!  wasn't expected this kind of repsonse!  thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a definite answer to this question as it's really dependent on the context of the query itself & the RDMS.

So in your case, you've done the research with 300 records. How about 3,000,000? Does it make a difference?

Personally I like Joins over Sub-Queries if I can help it, but like I said, this is really determined on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a declarative language, which **broadly** means you tell the database what you want, and its up to the database to decide to how best get it.

For that reason, a lot is to be said for writing your query in the way that makes its goal most obvious/readable (which is why a subquery may make sense here).

However, not all RDBMSs are equal, and the ability of the query optimizer to "equate" queries which are technically the same, but which are written differently, varies from db to db.

For instance, MySQL only has a nested-loop join algorithm at its disposal, and that can be an issue when dealing with subqueries for large data sets. You'll have to try it out with different data sets, taking a look at what the optimizer is doing behind the scenes.